# extract digits from filename

Tags: c++, file, filenames

I am working with file-names in C++. I need to know how to extract certain part of file-name?
File-names are like:

```
/home/xyz/123b45.dat

/home/xyz/012b06c.dat

/home/xyz/103b12d.dat

/home/xyz/066b50.dat
```

I want extract the two digits after 'b' (45, 06, 12, 50) from each file-name and store in an array. Could anybody please suggest how to do it...

Comment: Do you want to extract two digits from a file name, or do you want to visualize a vector of vectors?

Comment: vector of vectors was an old question! this question is about filename.... @juanchopanza

Comment: sorry!! forgot the title!! @juanchopanza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        auto suffix = line.find(".dat");
        if ( suffix != std::string::npos && suffix >= 2)
        {
            std::string part = line.substr(suffix-2, 2);
            parts.push_back(part);
        }
    }

    for ( auto & s : parts )
        std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Ouput for your input:

```
$ ./a.out < inp
45
06
12
50
```

Or, if you are **absolutely sure** every single line is well formed, you could replace the inside of the loop with:

```
std::string part = line.substr(line.size()-6, 2);
parts.push_back(part);
```

(Not recommended).

**Edit**: I noticed you changed the criteria of the question, so here's the replacement loop for the new criteria:

```
auto bpos = line.find_last_of('b');
if ( bpos != std::string::npos && line.size() >= bpos+2)
{
    std::string part = line.substr(bpos+1, 2);
    parts.push_back(part);
}
```

Note all of these variations have the same output.

You could chuck an [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) in there for good measure too.

**Final edit**: This is the full `bpos` version, `c++98` compatible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    // Read all available lines.
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        // Find the last 'b' in the line.
        std::string::size_type bpos = line.find_last_of('b');
        // Make sure the line is reasonable
        // (has a 'b' and at least 2 characters after)
        if ( bpos != std::string::npos && line.size() >= bpos+2)
        {
            // Get the 2 characters after the 'b', as a std::string.
            std::string part = line.substr(bpos+1, 2);
            // Push that onto the vector.
            parts.push_back(part);
        }
    }

    // This just prints out the vector for the example,
    // you can safely ignore it.
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = parts.begin();
    for ( ; it != parts.end(); ++it )
        std::cout << *it << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey @BoBTFish! thanks a lot!!
Could you please help me with the error I am getting...it says: "error: ‘bpos’ does not name a type"
What should I do?
thanks!!!

Comment: You are not compiling with `c++11` support. If that is not an option, the type of `bpos` is `std::string::size_type` (which is why I used `auto`, it would be easy to forget or be lazy and use the wrong type).

Comment: I am on C++98 mode. It says:
"error: range-based-for loops are not allowed in C++98 mode"

I don#t understand this.....I am not much advanced in c++...thank you for helping...please suggest how to implement loop then...

Comment: @user2346085 That is just from my output loop. You can delete that bit completely. I'll edit in a `c++98` version of the `bpos` version, but you really should read up on `c++11`. You are already 2 years out of date, and there is going to be a `c++14`. Maybe start [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html).

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll go through it asap! I'll wait for the c++98 version....
thanks!!!

Comment: I am not able to work with it....I don#t know why its not displaying anything. I think I am facing problem in the "std::cin" part....I have a loop where all the files inside a folder are read one at a time and this filename (/home/entire path/filename) is then to be passed to extract the two digits...

Comment: @user2346085 This is getting too much to do in comments and edits. Work your way through my example line by line, and make sure you understand everything it is doing. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is a good site to find out what functions do. Just change the loop in some way to populate `line` however you are getting each filename (and probably change that variable name if it will no longer contain input lines).

Comment: yeah I am trying....could you please suggest a small tip...if its 'a' in place of 'b' in the name....then the 'find_last_of' won't work right?? because there is an 'a' in '.dat' as well....any tips what to do then...
thanks a ton!

Comment: @user2346085 Oh come on, now you're not even trying. Look at the site I suggested, and maybe (*maybe*, it might not necessarily be the best option here) use [`std::string::rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind). I already showed you how to find the `.dat` position.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the title of your question, I assume you are storing the file names as `vectors` of `chars`. A much better way to do this would be to use `std::string`s. Strings allow all kinds of facility functions including tokenizing and retrieval of substrings and so forth (which is what you want to do).